# Does density of air decrease or increase with altitude and relation of this with temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, density

I think the air density decrease as due to gravity more air woul be near the earth but as the  hot air raises up doesn't it have momentarily increased the density at height (like in up troposphere) and then how the temperature plays role between them.... I dont understand that also.... Because the temperature decrease with altitude should have made the particles come closer and hence overall density increase..on this it could be that the coming closer of particles make rain but all these processes within themsrlves as confusing me really bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earth's atmosphere can be considered as a thin sheet of air extending from the earth's surface to about an altitude of 60 miles. It is the earth's gravity that holds the atmosphere.  The interconnection between temperature, pressure and density with altitude is as follows.

**About temperature variation with altitude:-**
The sun heats our earth's surface. Some of this heat warms the air near to the surface. The heated air by convection goes up, which gradually cools. *So the temperature of the air near the earth's surface is greater and the value decreases with increase in altitude.* This is why the speed of sound (which has a direct relation with temperature) decreases with altitude.

**About pressure variation with altitude:-**
The pressure of air is nothing but the weight of air column over a given surface. Suppose we are standing near the surface of earth. There will be a very long column of air above our head. So the weight of that air column will be maximum and hence pressure will be maximum. Now if you go up, there is air column above as well as below you. The air column below you will not contribute to the pressure on you. All that matters is the weight of the air column above you.But there is always less air above us than was present at a lower altitude. *So the pressure decreases with increase in altitude.*

**About density variation with altitude:-**
The density of air depends on both temperature and pressure through the equation of state (Remember how the pressure, volume and temperature are related in thermodynamics). The relation is given by (for ideal gas):

$$PV=nRT$$

where $n$ is the no. of moles of air molecules
$P$ is the pressure
$V$ is the volume
$R$ is the gas constant
and $T$ is the temperature.

To study the effect of density (which is mass per unit volume) we should know what is the effect of both pressure and temperature with altitude. It is seen that both $P$ and $T$ decreases with increase in altitude. Hence by the above relation

$$V=\frac{nRT}{P}$$

which means that if both pressure and temperature decreases there will be an increase in volume since the fall of pressure will be much more rapid than the fall of temperature with altitude.

*Since the volume increases with altitude and the mass remains unchanged, the density also decreases with altitude.*

The graphs showing the variation of temperature, pressure and density with altitude is as shown below:

[image]

[image]